# Cross Reference in 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I am working on a big document. So i would like to check whether my cross-reference is correctly referenced to the correct heading or not.

Example:

**Section 2:  Welcome to Word**

*"As stated in Section 2"* but if click 2 it takes me to 3 instead of Section 2.

Is there a way to see all the cross referenced numbers are referred to which titles on one go?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Go to Word options, click on the "Advanced" tab, and select "Show field codes instead of their values".

[image]